# Different font display on same (new) badge page

Tags: feature-request, badges

The [badges page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/badges) was recently updated to group like badges by category. This was supplemented by an update to the layout of the by-post awarded badges as well. Below is an excerpt from the [Editor badge](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/badges/3/editor):

[image]

The different fonts for some posts distinguish between questions and answers. More specifically, larger titles reference questions, while smaller titles reference answers. It does not appear to be the case when viewing similar pages on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com), which leads me to suggest that the view be made similar to that of a regular search:

[image]

In the above output, questions have a `Q:` prepended to the title, and similarly for answer being prepended with `A:`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The layout has been completely changed and now resembles

[image]

As such, the main error (font) doesn't show anymore.